# How to set association at the time of save/create in sequelizejs?

Tags: sequelize.js

For a simple model like this:

```js
var User = sequelize.define('User', { email: Sequelize.STRING });
var Team = sequelize.define('Team', { name: Sequelize.STRING });
User.belongsTo(Team);

Team.create({name:'blah'});
```

How do you store a new User and set its TeamId at the same time (same time here means in one INSERT)

This is important for cases where REFERENCE is mandatory (NOT NULL) and usual `user.setTeam(team)` which generates an UPDATE after an INSERT is not going to work.

Obviously extra team as an property in `User.create({ email: 'x', team: team })` will be ignored and the following:

```js
var user = User.build({email:'x'});
user.setTeam(team);
user.save();
```

generates one extra and completely wrong INSERT:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Users` (`TeamId`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) 
VALUES (4,'2015-08-19 18:10:36','2015-08-19 18:10:36');  
-- has no id or email
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the exact same problem

Comment: No unfortunately

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Old question, but maybe someone will benefit from this answer.

Assuming that `team` instance you want to add is already saved in database, you can add `save` parameter set to `false`, when adding association:

```
var user = User.build({email:'x'});
user.setTeam(team, {save: false});
user.save();
```

I've spent ages looking for that solution, I dont know why documentation doesn't mention it (or I couldn't find it there)

Comment: xersiee life saver

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.